# Visual studio project not opening

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have been working on a project for the last few months.Yesterday i was working with my project as well.There were no error until i installed GemBox.Spreedsheet.After installing gembox.speerdsheed,if u follow the usage procedure in the dev's website,u can see that using gembox spreadsheet requires you a license which you need to place in a new Public Sub.But just after i added the lines of code containing the license,i debugged my application and it gave me an error saying

** Could not load file or assembly 'Tabcontrolclass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a001c7cd8ca5785' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Tabcontrolclass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a001c7cd8ca5785'**

TabControlClass is my custom made tabcontrol...Anyway, after getting this error yesterday, i turned off my pc and today when i turned on my pc and opened my solution...The visual studio windows is blank.I noticed that the PLATFORM was changed to ANY CPU which had been x64 till today.Then i changed it back to x64.Then i went to solution explore and tried to open a form.But every form i try to open...vs takes forever to open the form showing "OPENING THE FILE..."..Then i closed and restarted vs, wen to solution explorer>references and WOOOOOAAAHHHHHHH...ALL MY REFERENCES GOT YELLOW TRIANGLE...I can't work on my project any more...Please somebody help me...

I tried changing the .net framework version from 4.5.2 to 4.5 and again setting it back to 4.5.2(4.5.2 is what i had been using) but with no luck.Please help me!

**UPDATE 1**

I created a new project..added the previous project to the new solution.I removed all the references.I added the, back but there's still the YELLOW TRIANGLE...What to do ?????

Comment: i believe there is version conflict with some libraries. my suggestion is to try deleting the references and add them again. and then do clean build of the solution.

Comment: But can you tell me why FORM OPENING takes forever??

Answer (score 0):

Well , i once ran into this problem and STACKOVERFLOW saved my day..Goto your project folder, search for the .vbproj file.Open it in notepad.Go to the bottom of the file...There you'ld see something like

```
<TARGET>
.........
...........
</TARGET>
==>
```

Remove everything from

```
  <TARGET>
```

to

```
  </TARGET>
```

or

```
  ==>
```

.Now save the file.Open your project.Remove all references and add them back.Hope this helps

Comment: O MY GOD..you are a genius!THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH..what i had been doing so far is creating a new project and adding all FORMs from previous project to the new one.it was killing me.Tnq u sooo much!

Comment: glad to help.Well i got this from stackoverflow itself..So i really don't deserve the credit